# iframe won't scroll unless reopened

Tags: javascript, iframe, scroll, ios8, mobile-safari

Currently I'm working on a widget which lives in an iframe on my page. I have the option for visitors to send me a message through a contact form inside the iframe (which is longer than the iframe, and so needs to scroll), however, when using Chrome on iOS8, the message form doesn't scroll unless i close and reopen the widget. Has anyone else come across this, or know what could be causing it?

The code that dictates the scrolling of the iframe is as follows:

```
frameDoc.body.firstChild.setAttribute(
   'style',
    ['width: 100%',
    'height: 100%',
    'overflow-x: hidden',
    'overflow-y: auto !important',
    '-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch !important'].join(';')
```

### );

Ok new problem. When i open the iframe, the'-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch' style is added, but when i close it and reopen, the style disappears. If i close it and reopen it AGAIN, the style is added again. My code is as follows:

```
if (
  existingStyle.indexOf('-webkit-overflow-scrolling') === -1) {
   frameFirstChild.setAttribute('style',
    `${existingStyle};-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;`);
  }
```

There is a setTimeout function wrapped around this statement, however changing the timeout does has no effect on whether the style is added or not. also my var definitions are as follows:

```
var frameFirstChild = this.getDOMNode().contentDocument.body.firstChild,
    existingStyle = frameFirstChild.getAttribute('style');
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason you use iFrame at all?

Comment: Have you tried to add your styles **after** the content of iFrame loads?

Comment: @skobaljic you're a genius! browser was loading too fast to apply the `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch` so i set a delay of 500ms, applied the style after, and it's working perfectly now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked it out. Had to move 
`existingStyle = frameFirstChild.getAttribute('style');` to inside before the if statement, while still wrapped inside setTimeout()